# Is ROS hard real time safe?

Tags: ros, real-time

I know that is a question that has been asked too many times, but still its not clear to me. I read online that it isn't but some people say that they control their robots under ROS in applications with hard real time constraints. So, because I need some technical arguments (rather than a plain "ros is not real time") I will be more specific (suppose we have ROS under a RTOS):

1. I read that ROS uses a TCP/IP-based communication for ROS topics and I know that TCP/IP is not reliable. That means I cannot use topics in a real time loop? For instance send a control signal to my system publishing it to a topic, and the system sending me some feedback via a topic?
2. If I have a RTOS (eg Linux+Xenomai) can I build a real time control loop for a robot using ROS, or ROS will be a bottleneck?

Maybe the above are naive or I lack some knowledge, so please enlighten me!

Note: I define as a hard real time system (eg in 1KHz), the system that can guarantee that we will not miss a thing (if the control loop fails to run every 1ms the system fails).

Comment: Remind me in a few days when I get to a computer and I'll explain.

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* jason, but I'm afraid that compound questions like this really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so you would be more likely to get comprehensive answers if you split them into separate question. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: Can you please clarify your definition of "real time". I assume you mean that the control updates at faster than 25Hz otherwise.

Comment: @Shahbaz As real time I define a system that updates the control in some high frequency (eg 200Hz+), but the most important is to provide guarantees that every control cycle will be performed in 200Hz, and we don't lose control cycles due to jitter.

Comment: @jason, realtime doesn't relate to fast. You are correct that a realtime system guarantees deadlines. I understand that you are searching for a fast system, but I'm clarifying for JamesR that a realtime system could be designed for any speed, even if the cycle time is one day!

Comment: Yes @Shahbaz, totally agree with you. Just with one cycle a day is easy to be implemented in practice by a non-real time system. A proper real time system is more useful in "harsh" conditions.

Comment: That's generally true. Slower realtime systems are not unrealistic though. Your typical airport would ideally run as a realtime system that would guarantee flight times for example with a maximum of 2 hours delay. They also thought nonrealtime is fine for such large delays and now we occasionally suffer from canceled or largely delayed flights.

Comment: You say that "TCP/IP is not reliable". Actually, TCP is built for achieving reliable transmission (it guarantees that either your data is received correctly, completely, and in the right sequence [within the constraints of uniqueness of checksums], or that you will be notified if this is not possible [e.g. due to interrupted path between stations]), but it cannot guarantee any delay because of possible retransmissions.

Answer (score 5):

ROS is not a real-time operating system.  The purpose of ROS was not to be like VXWorx (which is what the Mars Curiosity rover uses).  ROS was developed to be a simple, generic, reusable platform for everyone to contribute to and use.  Developers would be able to add their own abstracted modules, building a rich community of reusable code.  The key here is that ROS is meant to save development time, not to ensure real-time operations.  This addresses your point #6.

Simplest reason ROS is not real-time: the version of Linux it sits on is not real-time.

To point 1, the unreliability of TCP/IP is a good point, but in itself, that doesn't mean that a system with TCP/IP cannot be a real-time system.  "Real-time" simply means that 2 guarantees are always made:

1) a task is guaranteed to have a completion time - an absolute deadline,
and
2) if that deadline cannot be achieved, a warning about this failure will be made.

That should also explain points 2 & 3.

Not sure about point 4.

For point 5: Yes, there is a benefit, but for some architectures to be able to accomplish this, we would need a real-time OS slice (also called a base operating layer), and this may be too burdensome for some projects.

I hope that helps,
Ryan

Comment: So, If I patch the linux kernel (eg with Xenomai) and have a RTOS underneath ROS, I would be able to use every ROS functionalies (eg ROS topics) without creating a bottleneck, breaking the realtimeness of my control loop?

Comment: @jason, ROS is non-realtime by nature. Making it run on a realtime system doesn't make it real-time at all.